# How to make Intellij export SQL inserts in Oracle friendly format

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export data from Intellij as INSERT statements. And then import them to oracle. I keep getting `ORA-01843: not a valid month` error. How can I get it to work? My .sql file is over 600 MB large so I can't just manually correct all the statements.

Those are the fields that are problematic:

```
"CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE,
"TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

Of course in reality it has much more but for this question I only include those that cause problems.

In Intellij I run `SELECT * FROM table_name` and then in results view I click export data. In Export Data window I choose Extractor: SQL Inserts and then click Export to File. In that file there are SQL statements where CREATED is for example `'2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC'` and TIMESTAMP is for example `'2023-02-20 14:57:49.66 +00:00'`

When I try to import this file using Oracle SQL Developer then all those inserts fail because `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Is there something that I can do to either make Intellij export in Oracle friendly format or to make Oracle SQL Developer accept format that I currently have?

Comment: If you have the Ultimate Edition, you can change the SQL dialect to "Oracle" (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-dialects.html)

Comment: Thanks. I already have it set to Oracle. At least when I right click this text area where I have SQL statements then it already shows: Change Dialect (Oracle). Because it shows Oracle in parentheses. Even selected it again to be sure. But it still generates the same format for dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Developer you can do

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR';
```

before running the inserts.

You can also change that in the preferences, but if you only want it to apply for the current session use `alter`.

Depending on your other columns and how they are formatted in your script you might also want to do:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Answer (score 1):

`'2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC'` is not a timestamp, it is a string literal. Oracle will try to be helpful when you try to insert a string into a timestamp column and will implicitly convert from one data type to another but:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (created) VALUES ('2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC');
```

Will, effectively be converted into:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (created)
VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    '2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC',
    ( SELECT value
      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
      WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT' )
  )
);
```

If the session parameter does not match the format then you will get an exception (or worse, it matches but the terms are in the wrong order so your imported data is now incorrect).

What you should do is not use strings for timestamps and either:

- Use a timestamp literal `TIMESTAMP '2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC'`
- or explicitly use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` with the correct format model `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-02-27 11:54:51.0 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR')`

---

Given that your timestamps are already in a format compatible with timestamp literals, you may be able to do a find-replace over your generated file on a regular expression matching `'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d* ([A-Z_]+|[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})'` (or something similar) and replace it with the same string with `TIMESTAMP`  prepended.